# How to implement a Native Android Service?

Tags: android, c++, service, android-ndk

I need to implement a Service entirely from C/C++ using the NDK but there seems to be no NativeService equivalent for the supported NativeActivity class. I understand from reading around that the Binder class is not provided via the NDK and would be grateful if someone can explain why this prevents a Native Service from working in Android and whether there are any workarounds other than the unpalatable use of an unsupported class/library.

One scheme that occurs to me is just to write a NativeActivity and access it via intents, writing only the service parts in Java for the standard Android SDK.  Can anyone see anything wrong with this approach ?  It has the advantage of avoiding the use of JNI at least...

Thanks,

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215462/how-to-create-a-android-native-service-and-use-binder-to-communicate-with-it)

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I have already seen that question and was seeking further elucidation on the specifiec issues in my post.