# Test Android NDK executables on PC without any JNI or upper layers

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk

I am learning Binders in Android, so I want to test whether my sample applications written in C/C++ are working properly. I am on a linux based PC.

When I searched on Google, every example was implementing a JNI layer, which I think don't is required as I can use simple [logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629308/any-simple-or-easy-way-to-debug-android-ndk-code) facilities.

Is there a way that I can test my (android-based) executables directly on my PC? Hope I am clear.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're compiling against `android/log.h`, whatever system you want to run the executable on will have to have the proper instruction set and have `android/log.h`.

You could easily switch all of your android prints to print to STDOUT (printf, etc.) and then recompile on whatever system that you're using using it's compiler (gcc, etc.).

Comment: Suppose I made a service using Binder which prints 'hello world'. Now I cannot test it on linux system, because linux do not have binders. I wanted to know that does Android NDK create such testable Android environment where I can test my 'hello world' binder service?

Comment: Looking at this [about how binders aren't supposed to be available to the NDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215462/how-to-create-a-android-native-service-and-use-binder-to-communicate-with-it), I don't think it'd be available. Sorry about that.

If you can remove the binder, you can test the rest of the code